# How to save and retrieve Matrix4 object of flutter's Vector_math library?

Tags: matrix, flutter, save

I have ValueNotifier which is initialized with Matrix4. I can transform my view. Now I want to somehow save the current value of ValueNotifier in SQLite and again on loading initialize my ValueNotifier with saved Matrix4 value. Below is code:

```
ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());

MatrixGestureDetector(
              onMatrixUpdate: (matrix, translationMatrix, scaleMatrix, rotationMatrix) {
                notifier.value = matrix;
              },
              child: AnimatedBuilder(animation: notifier,
                  builder: (context, child) {

                    return Transform(
                      transform: notifier.value,
                      child: Container(
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        color: Colors.yellow,

                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Matrix4` has a getter `storage` which returns an list of 16 doubles. It also has named constructors (`.fromList` and `.fromFloat64List`) as well as the normal constructor (which takes 16 individual doubles) which will construct a `Matrix4` back from its component parts.

Depending on how you'd like to store the data in SQLite you could use a combination of these. If you wanted to store all 16 doubles as columns in the database, use `storage[0], storage[1], ...` as your column values. You might also want to store it a character-separated string of 16 values. You could print append all 16 values with `List.join(' ')` and parse them back out with `String.split(' ')`.

The most efficient way (but least human readable) is probably to store it as a BLOB of 128 bytes. Use `matrix.storage.buffer.asUint8List()` to convert `matrix` to bytes, and use `Matrix4.fromBuffer(bytes.buffer, 0)` to construct a matrix from a `Uint8List` called `bytes`.